# Simple equation.

Tags: arithmetic

I was browsing the web and came across this question:

```
10 + 10  x 10
```

I would argue

> BODMAS

would apply, using high school math.

B rackets,
O rder
D ivision 
M ultiplication 
A ddition
S ubtraction

I would place the brackets so: 10 + (10 x 10)
Then I would do multiplication so: (10x10) = 100
Then Addition so: 10 + (10 x10) =

> 110

.

Some people argue BODMAS does not apply, if so why? Because I can't see how you could get 200.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, if you parse it from left to right, you end up at 200.

Comment: Apart from that, I know that as BEDMAS (E for exponent). What Order is meant?

Comment: I was taught order meant powers of. I know indices / exponents are more common and make more sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BODMAS surely **does** apply here. So multiplication should be performed before addition.

You are correct.

$$10 + 10\times 10 = 110$$

Comment: Awesome thanks!

Comment: If you can, refer those people who seem to think that the Order of Operations can be circumvented to this website; I'm sure many of our members would love to set them straight, myself included.

Comment: @amWhy: Sounds delicious! :-) +1